# What were the "unforeseen circumstances" that accelerated V's plan?

Tags: movie, vertigo-comics, v-for-vendetta

In *V for Vendetta* film, V asks for Evey's help in his plan to kill Bishop Lilliman:

> I was wondering if your offer to help was still standing. It appears unforeseen circumstances have accelerated my original plan. As a result, I'm in need of someone with some theatrical skill.

It seems to me that V's mission was going very much according to plan; he was on track to meet his one-year deadline. To what unforeseen circumstances does he refer?

Comment: Was this said in the movie or the comic?  Trying to find in comic and failing.

Comment: @Radhil I'm referring to the movie version. I don't have a copy of the comic handy to check if it's there as well. I'll try searching online for the text.

Comment: No, the offer of help is there, but the tone of V accepting is much different, and the words are not the same.  I would think that Finch being on the case would have been what he was referring to, but going back through the comic Finch was worked so seamlessly into the plan that's hard to fathom.  Watched the movie but not as familiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original source comic, it would appear that the reason V was so keen to accept Evey's offer of help was simply that it was *convenient to his planning*. Presumably he'd intercepted one of the Bishop's semi-regular communications with the pimp who supplied his underage girls and knew that this presented an opportunity to attack him at a moment of weakness; both in terms of his personal security and in terms of his moral frailty.

[image]

Notably, in the [original version](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/V-for-Vendetta.html) of the script, the line remains much unchanged

> **EVEY:** *I want to help you, V.  I want to do something.  Can we make a
> deal?*
>
> **V:** *Yes.  I think we can make a deal if you like.  I think I know a way
> you could help me very soon indeed.*

---

If I had to guess, the "unforeseen circumstances" line reflects a slight change between the comics and the film. At this point in the film Finch has already discovered the connection between V and Larkhill (by looking at Prothero's record), something that doesn't occur in the books until far later (when he discovers the Doctor's diary).